# typescript, Array.prototype.map() has error 'expression is not callable' when the callee array is union with empty array

Tags: typescript

I have a type alias `Data` which is a union of two data structure -- one contain array that is not empty while the other is empty:

```js
const dataEmptyArray = { data: [] }
const dataNotEmptyArray = { data: [1, 2, 3] }

type DataEmptyArray = typeof dataEmptyArray
type DataNotEmptyArray = typeof dataNotEmptyArray

type Data = DataNotEmptyArray | DataEmptyArray // <--- union here

function foo(arg:Data) {
  if (arg && arg.data && Array.isArray(arg.data)) {
    return arg.data.map( (d:(never|number)) => d)
    //              ^^^<--------- this expression is not callable   
  } else {
    return 'no data'
  }
}

const result = foo(dataEmptyArray)
```

However, when I try to call Array.prototype.map() on the array I have an error said:
"this expression is not callable"

The above snippet can be found [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggogWwA5QJ4EEBO+C2MAvDAN7xIIBcMA2gLowC+AsAFCiSyLIA5EFHRY8hYmUrVk9BgEYANDABMygMwsOnLjgwBTGABEaonASIlye-SABmM1JnMTsu7AeM0hI5+MtSNvaOPmb+xFzunibIUjEIoX4WkgA+XshhySQA9NkwADwAtMUwAK5gAJbgMAAW+vj6kZx25cBQVWAwdiAgABQI+ADmtPEAlJRcMDAVDv1DMABkCzADgwB0-AiLy1lrFRBZc+ubo+MUk1MwDVCl+J2rGzRraAgYvTC9cLS9YPoAbvUUmBSmgAEb1U5kAB88FGFymuUuSORUwAeuiisUsViYFAavsYPoAB4YBoQCAdaYQGBgYQwYAIAA2jIQoMZhimF1YhMZEEM504SOut06AHJaY5RVyuNouDxoFd9BBSozYORun1NplXHCdJwgA)

I notice, I can eliminate the type error if I define the alias of Data as intersection:

```js
type Data = DataNotEmptyArray & DataEmptyArray
```

or simply don't union with `DataEmptyArray`

```js
type Data = DataNotEmptyArray
```

Could you please explain why union with empty Array is a problem ? 
What does it mean when it said "the expression is not callable"?
thanks!!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Option 1

Update typescript to **4.2+** (I recommend the latest version)

This will work for `.map`, but it **will not work for `.reduce`, `.every`, `.find` and `.filter`**

(Edit 2023-05-17: `.every`, `.find` and `.filter` should be fixed in the next release TypeScript 5.2?)

As of May 2023 there is an open issue about the `.reduce` case:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44063

## Option 2

In the meantime you can add `as any[]` to get rid of the error:
For `.map`:

```
const arr: number[] | string[] = [];
// Add as any[]
(arr as any[]).map((a: number | string, index: number) => { 
    return index
});
```

For `.reduce`:

```
const arr: number[] | string[] = [];
// Add as any[]
(arr as any[]).reduce((acc: number | string, val: number|string) => { 
    return `${acc} ${val}`
},'');
```

### More information

The issue for `.map`:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36390

The issue for the `.every`, `.find` and `.filter` cases:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373

Comment: Thanks. After update to TypeScript 4.3 issue gone

Comment: Option 2 works great! Thank you!

Comment: In case anyone else wonder it's not just for `reduce` but also for `filter`, `find`, etc. Here's the issue tracking them all: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373

Comment: @maxime1992 Thanks for pointing out, I have updated the answer to include these. If you are still looking for a solution, `Option 2` (See above) should work for all of these

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373 was [closed as fixed today](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373#event-9262876032).

Comment: @Inigo Thanks, updated the answer. Will update again including which version will fix when it is released

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not really the empty array. If you have a case with the 2 arrays with different types for example if array with number and string

```
const dataEmptyArray = { data: ['my string'] };
const dataNotEmptyArray = { data: [1, 2, 3] };
```

This viewed as a limitation from TS, he won't be able to handle the union type `string[] | number[]` as for your case `never[]|number[]`. He will not assume that it's Array which if you cast to that you will be able to call the map.

Also form the raised issue on github https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33591

> We don't have any way to check this in a way that's well-bounded in terms of analysis time.
>   (...)
>
> The only way to correctly check this program is to re-check the body of the inner body 3 * 3 * 3 times (!), and TS would need to clear its cache of expression types on each invocation (something which is currently architecturally impossible). It's not even clear what we'd show for arr's type here!

Comment: ummm..... i don't think i understand. if it is a type Array, we should be able to call map on it. Is that so difficult? Really? i admit i don't know the inner working ofTS, but this seem to be such an obvious thing as a limitations.

Comment: At the end Array and [] are not 100 % the same thing. I think at some point ts would Infer the type of [1,2,3] as [number, number, number] instead of number[] or Array<number>