# I am getting a red squiggle under my map function but my code is still compiling, why is this and how can I fix it?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, array.prototype.map

This is the array I am iterating through:

```
[
        {
            "Categories": [
              {
                "Name": "Program",
                "Description": "This is a program",
                "Errors": [
                  {
                    "Name": "Program_not_found",
                    "Value": 1,
                    "Description": "There is an error in this program."
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "Name": "ProgramTwo",
                "Description": "This is programTwo.",
                "Errors": [
                  {
                    "Name": "ProgramTwo is not found",
                    "Value": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "ProgramTwo is missing data",
                    "Value": 2
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]  
          }
    ]
```

In another file, I am iterating through this data and getting a red squiggle under map here:

```
{Errors.map(({Name, Value, Description}, key)
```

My code compiles and it shows the information correctly.  I don't understand why the map function has a red squiggle under it if the code is compiling.  When I hover over .map it doesn't give any information about the error.  I am hoping someone can tell me why this is happening and how to fix it.  This is what my component looks like:

```
const Categories = () => {
return (
<h1>Error Codes</h1>
<div className="error-codes">
        {errorCodes.map(({Categories}, key) => (
          <div key={key}>
            {Categories.map(({Name, Description, Errors}, key) => (
              <div key={key}>
                <p>{Name}</p>
                <p>{Description}</p>
                {Errors.map(({Name, Value, Description}, key) => ( //Getting red squiggle under map here
                  <div key={key}>
                    <p>{Name}</p>
                    <p>{Value}</p>
                    <p>{Description}</p>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
)
}
export default Categories;
```

Comment: Maybe `Errors` could be null or undefined (e.g. when initialized) and then it would have no attribute `map`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just a guess but it might your linter, this linter wants to tell you that your line is too long.
2. Another guess is that you do not initialize `Errors` to be an array type. Since the type is not declared you linter wants to tell you this might not work, since `Errors` yould have any type.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue was related to typescript.  I was able to make the error go away by doing this: {(Errors as any []).map.  I found this solution here: [typescript, Array.prototype.map() has error 'expression is not callable' when the callee array is union with empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772314/typescript-array-prototype-map-has-error-expression-is-not-callable-when-th)